# while installing vc_redist.x64.exe, getting error "Failed to configure per-machine MSU package."

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-c++-2010, redistributable

While I am trying to install vc_redist.x64.exe on Windows 8.1
getting following error:

> Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.

Comment: Please try to download vc_redist "UPDATE 3" packages from Microsoft. That's work to me.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Posting answer to my own question as I found it here and was hidden in bottom somewhere -

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64baed8c-b00c-40d5-b19a-99b26a11516e/visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015-rc-fails-on-windows-server-2012?forum=vssetup

This is because the OS failed to install the required update Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.

However, you can install it by extracting that update to a folder (e.g. XXXX), and execute following cmdlet. You can find the Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu at below.

C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\469A82B09E217DDCF849181A586DF1C97C0C5C85\packages\Patch\amd64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu

copy this file to a folder you like, and

> Create a folder XXXX in that and execute following commands from Admin command propmt
>
> wusa.exe Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu /extract:XXXX
>
> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:XXXX\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab
>
> vc_redist.x64.exe /repair

(last command need not be run. Just execute vc_redist.x64.exe once again)

this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. The path to the .msu was different though. I experienced the issue while installing VS 2015 that is just released. If you do also, wait until it fails, then go to the installation log and find the actual location of the package. It was "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" for my environment.

Comment: I kept getting "KB2999226 - Access is denied" error when installing Visual Studio 2015. Followed the above steps except referenced the Windows 6.1 msu file [for Windows 7]. Success!

Comment: I got Error 87 "The add-package option is unknown". There is no add-package in the DISM OPTIONS list when using the command DISM.EXE /?. My system is Windows 8.1 pro and I got the KB2999226 fail error when installing the VS 2015 Professional.

Comment: If you get that error 87 "the add-package option is unkown," the reason can be that the "Windows Modules Installer" service is not running.

Comment: Note - to re-iterate you MUST run the wusa command as administrator or you'll get no errors and no cab files.

Comment: Unfortunately I get : DISM error DISM Package Manager: PID=2872 The package Package_for_KB2999226 is not applicable to the image. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessPackageChange

Comment: Update on the DISM error. Although Windows Update said I had Win7 SP1 installed, after a few more updates the same Win7 SP1 update said it needed to be installed - leading me to believe WU history lied. The SP1 update took a LONG time, and then the vcredist worked, without having to extract the cab.

Comment: Probably the installation of KB2999226 failed because of prerequisites has not been met. Manually extract and install the patch may not be a good idea. I have solve the problem in an other way as mentioned in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35567962/1131246.

Comment: @Cito, a +plus vote for you. "Windows Modules Installer service" was disabled, the missing ingredient.

Answer (score 16):

I would like to give you a background on Universal CRT this would help you in understanding as to why the system should be updated before installing vc_redist.x64.exe.

1. A large portion of the C-runtime moved into the OS in Windows 10 (ucrtbase.dll) and is serviced just like any other OS DLL (e.g. kernel32.dll).  It is no longer serviced by Visual Studio directly.  MSU packages are the file type for Windows Updates.
2. In order to get the Windows 10 Universal CRT to earlier OSes, Windows Update packages were created to bring this OS component downlevel.  KB2999226 brings the Windows 10 RTM Universal CRT to downlevel platforms (Windows Vista through Windows 8.1).  KB3118401 brings Windows 10 November Update to the Universal CRT to downlevel platforms.

   - Windows XP (latest SP) is an exception here.  Windows Servicing does not provide downlevel packages for that OS, so Visual Studio (Visual C++) provides a mechanism to install the UCRT into System32 via the VCRedist and MSMs.
3. The Windows Universal Runtime is included in the VC Redist exe package as it has dependency on the Windows Universal Runtime (KB2999226).
4. Windows 10 is the only OS that ships the UCRT in-box.  All prior OSes obtain the UCRT via Windows Update only.  This applies to all Vista->8.1 and associated Server SKUs.

For Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 the Windows Universal Runtime must be installed via KB2999226. However it has a prerequisite update KB2919355 which contains updates that facilitate installing the KB2999226 package.

Why does KB2999226 not always install when the runtime is installed from the redistributable?  What could prevent KB2999226 from installing as part of the runtime?

The UCRT MSU included in the VCRedist is installed by making a call into the Windows Update service and the KB can fail to install based upon Windows Update service activity/state:

1. If the machine has not updated to the required servicing baseline, the UCRT MSU will be viewed as being “Not Applicable”.
   Ensure KB2919355 is installed. Also, there were known issues with KB2919355  so before this the following hotfix should be installed.
   KB2939087
   KB2975061
2. If the Windows Update service is installing other updates when the VCRedist installs, you can either see long delays or errors indicating the machine is busy.

   - This one can be resolved by waiting and trying again later (which may be why installing via Windows Update UI at a later time succeeds).
3. If the Windows Update service is in a non-ready state, you can see errors reflecting that.

   - We recently investigated a failure with an error code indicating the WUSA service was shutting down.
4. To identify if the prerequisite KB2919355 is installed there are 2 options:

   1. Registry key:
      64bit hive

      ```
      HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14
      CurrentState = 112
      ```

      32bit hive

      ```
      HKLM\SOFTWARE\[WOW6432Node\]Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14
      CurrentState = 112
      ```
   2. Or check the file version of:

      ```
      C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wuaueng.dll
      C:\Windows\System32\wuaueng.dll
      ```

      is 7.9.9600.17031  or later

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem but in my case I was trying to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on Windows Server 2012 R2. However the root cause should be the same.

In short, you need to install the prerequisites of KB2999226.

In more details, the installation log I got stated that the installation for Windows Update KB2999226 failed. According to the Microsoft website [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226):

> Prerequisites To install this update, you must have [April 2014 update
>   rollup for Windows RT 8.1, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2
>   (2919355)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355) installed in Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2. Or,
>   [install Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976932).
>   Or, [install Service Pack 2 for Windows Vista and for Windows Server
>   2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948465).

After I have installed April 2014 on my Windows Server 2012 R2, I am able to install the Visual C++ Redistributable correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much. Our Windows 2008 R2 Server needed to have service pack 1 installed before I could get the KB to install.

Answer (score 1):

The OS failed to install the required update Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
However I tried to find the particular update from -

```
C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\469A82B09E217DDCF849181A586DF1C97C0C5C85\packages\Patch\amd64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
```

I couldn't find it there so I installed the kb2999226 update from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234) (Windows 10 Universal C runtime)

Then I installed the update according to my OS and after that It was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case and while installing VS 2015 on Windows7 64x SP1, I experienced the same so tried to cancel and download/install the KBKB2999226 separately and for some reason the standalone update installer also get stuck searching for updates.

[image]

## Here what I did:

1. When the VS installer stuck at the KB2999226 update I clicked cancel.
2. Installer took me back to confirm cancellation, waited for a while then opened the windows task manager and ended the process of **wuse.exe** (windows standalone update installer)
3. On the VS installer clicked "No" to return to installation process. The process was completed without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I also got that error when trying to install the **Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable** on my Windows 7 SP1 machine.

I solved my problem by installing the **Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable** from here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0