# Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Runtime wont finish installing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, installation, runtime, redistributable

I hope this sort of question is accepted here.

I'm currently trying to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Runtime and it's getting stuck near the end, with the text, "Processing: Windows81_x64" and it never progresses beyond that.

I have indeed uninstalled the 2015 Visual C++ files (though I have a lot of older versions still installed). No further Windows updates are available.

I'm at a loss, and I certainly hope someone can help! Thanks for reading, in any case.

Comment: I saw that someone marked this question down, but I want to be as clear and helpful as possible, especially because I need this fixed.

I've looked up every answer on this I could find and none of them have worked, or been relevant to my situation (i.e. different result from a method I already tried, etc.)

Can someone please tell me what more information I should add?

Comment: Hi Midori, please reboot your computer and login with the administrator account, then temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up the %temp% folder, re-run this Visual C++ 2015 installer as administrator, if this issue persists, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link. Meanwhile, please check this similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233672/installation-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-stuck-at-processing-window

Comment: Thanks for the help, Sara.

What I ended up doing was installing some (other) Steam games and rebooting my computer. One of the other games must have installed the file properly, since previous reboots did not solve this issue.

I'm still not entirely sure why that would have worked while the Micorosoft exe itself didn't, but in any case, it appears this issue has been solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows 81_x64 is a file for Windows 8.1, so the first thing I'd do is verify that you're running Windows 8.1. If not, go back to the VS download page and download the right version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am definitely running Windows 8.1 (Pro). I've also checked the updates and I'm all up-to-date already.