# Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 Deleted and can't reinstall

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-c++, installation, command-prompt

A few months ago I had Visual Studio IDE then uninstalled it and(stupidly) uninstalled all the Visual C++ Redistributables along with it. I managed to install all the versions from 2005 up to 2013, but I can't seem to get the 2015 version running. I get stuck on "processing:   windows81_x64" and "processing:   windows81_x86"  screens.

I'm trying to use python in command prompt "C:>python" and I get this error "The program cant start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer". I'm also getting similar error messages with other software, python is just an example.

I've tried manually deleting and reinstalling the packages , which obviously hasn't worked. I've also tried using the "major geeks" installer (I know its a 'use at my own risk' software) but it only installed up to 2010 files.

On a side note, Windows update isn't working for me either, not sure if that has anything to do with the issue or not

Any help appreciated

Comment: Hi, since the windows update also not works, I suppose this issue more relates to your environment. What the detail error message do you meet? Please try to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-troubleshooting to troubleshoot the failed windows update and follow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system to check and repair your OS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233672/installation-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-stuck-at-processing-window/41237005 might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know what the issue was, but I reinstalled windows 10 and everything now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based roughly on the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41237005/446106, try installing KB2999226 for your version of Windows.

For me the installer itself gets stuck searching for updates - in this case, extract the .cab file from the .msu installer and installing it manually with `dism /online /add-package /packagepath:Windows<XXX>-KB2999226-x64.cab`.