# Why does the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (x86) installer crash when i try to install it?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

i'm trying to install OBS Studio, and i ran into this error while downloading it.

> Setup Failed
>   One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup.
>   For more information see the log file.

and the error is

> 0x80240017 Unspecified Error

And the log file looks like this.

```
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:32]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\Kaelan\Downloads\vc2017redist_x86.exe, cmdline: ''
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20180912164132.log'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\Downloads\vc2017redist_x86.exe'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\Downloads\'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) - 14.14.26429'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:33]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20180912164132_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86_rollback.log'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20180912164132_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20180912164132_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86_rollback.log'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\Kaelan\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20180912164132_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:34]i300: Apply begin
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:36]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Kaelan\AppData\Local\Temp\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}\.be\VC_redist.x86.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}\VC_redist.x86.exe'
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: ,,x86,14.0,bundle, version: 14.14.26429.4
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0D64:17E4][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\564F02E6419B9858949B0CD5A65E2C8C0944DD88\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu.
[0D64:17E4][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7753EC39-3039-3629-98BE-447C5D869C09}v14.14.26429\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi.
[0D64:17E4][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i304: Verified existing payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7753EC39-3039-3629-98BE-447C5D869C09}v14.14.26429\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\cab1.cab.
[0D64:17E4][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6F0267F3-7467-350D-A8C8-33B72E3658D8}v14.14.26429\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi.
[0D64:17E4][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i304: Verified existing payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{6F0267F3-7467-350D-A8C8-33B72E3658D8}v14.14.26429\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\cab1.cab.
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:40]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\564F02E6419B9858949B0CD5A65E2C8C0944DD88\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\564F02E6419B9858949B0CD5A65E2C8C0944DD88\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:41]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:41]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:41]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x86, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:41]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:41]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:41]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: ,,x86,14.0,bundle
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:41]i352: Removing cached bundle: {2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}\
[0D64:1760][2018-09-12T16:41:41]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{2019b6a0-8533-4a04-ac0e-b2c10bdb9841}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[024C:1088][2018-09-12T16:41:42]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Can someone help me?

**OS: Windows 7 PRO**

**State: Good**

**On a VM: Yes**

**Bits: 32 (x86)**

Comment: If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Comment: [Another question about this runtime here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758087/129130). I would use the decompile bundle approach that you find in my answer there, and then try to install the MSU directly and interactively and check for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

***Disabled Windows Update?***: I am wondering if you have disabled Windows Update on that virtual? What is failing is **`Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu`** - an update for the Universal C Runtime in Windows. This Windows Update may have other Windows Updates as prerequisites before it can install.

***Run Interactive & Check Logs***: You can test by running **`Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu`** interactively to see if there are any interactive error messages, or **check the system's event log** (which I would do first) to see if there are concrete error messages.

***Decompile Setup***: To decompile this WiX Burn-created **`setup.exe`**, you need to use WiX's **`dark.exe`** tool ([how-to towards bottom in section 4 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files/48482546#48482546)). It might be quicker to [just download **`Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu`** from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49077) instead, and then try to run it interactively on the virtual.

***Other Tests***: If that leads nowhere there are many options to try. I like to create a new local admin account and run the installation via that account as my first test. This is to rule out profile problems and similar nonsense. Not likely in this case I think, but a useful little test. There could be a plethora of other problems, for example policies and security software interference, etc...

Comment: Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu says "The update is not applicable to your computer."

Comment: Is this the software? https://obsproject.com/download. Your log indicates a WiX installer, but what I see there is an NSIS installer by the looks of it. Are you sure you have the latest installer?

Comment: It looks like this update is for Vista and Windows Server 2008 only: [KB2999226](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2999226). Try to decompile the Burn bundle using the approach I have linked to above and then run the other setups and runtimes manually instead. Or perhaps look for a newer installer. With that said [there are some Windows 7 download links here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the log file, it seems the OS failed to install the required update **Window6.1-KB2999223-x86.msu**. We can try to extract this update to a folder and execute the following cmdlet.

You can find the Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu at below.

C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\564F02E6419B9858949B0CD5A65E2C8C0944DD88\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu
copy this file to a folder you like, and

- Create a folder XXXX in that and execute following commands from
  Admin command prompt

  wusa.exe Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu /extract:XXXX

  DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package
  /PackagePath:XXXX\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab

  vc_redist.x64.exe /repair last command need not be run. Just execute
  exe once again.

For more detail information, please check [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536606/while-installing-vc-redist-x64-exe-getting-error-failed-to-configure-per-machi).

Comment: But do I have to use "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Windows 7 Updates\Windows6.1\" as the directory, or just use "cd C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Windows 7 Updates\Windows6.1"?