# Inspecting log file to find out reason for installation failure of vcredist.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-7, vcredist

I'm trying to run the Microsoft C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) - 14.16.27027 on a Windows 7 machine.

The setup fails, stating "Unknown error 0x80240017".

It also outputs a log file which I have stated below.

How could I find out what the real problem is?

Thank you.

Log file:

```
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i001: Burn v3.10.1.2213, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\vcredist2017.exe
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i009: Command Line: ''
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20190427174049.log'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\vcredist2017.exe'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) - 14.16.27027'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[0AC4:0AD8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '14.16.27027.1'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:50]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0AC4:0AD8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20190427174049_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86_rollback.log'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20190427174049_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20190427174049_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86_rollback.log'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20190427174049_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i300: Apply begin
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:52]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:54]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:54]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:40:54]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:40:55]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:40:55]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}\.be\VC_redist.x86.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}\VC_redist.x86.exe'
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x86,x86,14.16,bundle, version: 14.16.27027.1
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0B9C:0BB0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[0B9C:0BB0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5EEFCEFB-E5F7-4C82-99A5-813F04AA4FBD}v14.16.27024\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi.
[0B9C:0BB0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i304: Verified existing payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5EEFCEFB-E5F7-4C82-99A5-813F04AA4FBD}v14.16.27024\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\cab1.cab.
[0B9C:0BB0][2019-04-27T17:41:05]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7258184A-EC44-4B1A-A7D3-68D85A35BFD0}v14.16.27024\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi.
[0B9C:0BB0][2019-04-27T17:41:06]i304: Verified existing payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7258184A-EC44-4B1A-A7D3-68D85A35BFD0}v14.16.27024\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\cab1.cab.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:06]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:11]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x86,x86,14.16,bundle
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i352: Removing cached bundle: {39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}\
[0B9C:0BA0][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{39e28474-b67b-4209-af1b-e9ad0a83d8ca}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: See (or maybe a dupe)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31536606/while-installing-vc-redist-x64-exe-getting-error-failed-to-configure-per-machi

Comment: 0x80240017=WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE becasue already have newer UCRT update installed. install 2019 runtime which is fully compatible to 2015/2017

Comment: @magicandre1981 Can you please explain why 2019 is "better suited" than 2017?

Comment: 2019 is binary compatible to 2015 and 2017 so 2019 runtime replaces the old 2015/2017 ones. I posted the real cause of your install issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The C++ 2019 runtimes are not yet released, right?

Comment: the 2019 still requires Sp1. Here are the links: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs shows that installing the [MSU of the Universal C Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) fails with error `0x80240017` which means `WU_E_NOT_APPLICABLE`:

```
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:41:11]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
```

This can have several causes:

1. missing pre- requirements
2. you already have a newer version installed.

> [0AC4:0AC8][2019-04-27T17:40:49]i001: Burn v3.10.1.2213, **Windows v6.1
>   (Build 7600: Service Pack 0)**, path:
>   C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\vcredist2017.exe

This means you run Windows 7 RTM without the Sp1, but the runtime requires the Sp1, that is why you get the error message.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would I still the Windows 7 SP1 if I used the C++ 2019 runtimes instead?